# OTA in nanoframework, not able to download the file from azure blob. ESP32

Tags: ssl, azure-blob-storage, tls1.2, ota, nanoframework

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.Get("https://xdatas.blob.core.windows.net/ota/test.pe");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsString();

for _httpClient.HttpsAuthentCert = new X509Certificate()// iam using same from https://github.com/BWalti/nf-ssl/blob/main/nf-ssl/Resources/AzureRootCerts.pem

but this is the error iam getting
Issue : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException

**https://github.com/BWalti/nf-ssl** This is the same code iam using the only change is
storageAccountBaseUri : https://firmwarefilestest.blob.core.windows.net/ota/
storageAccountFileNames :
nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32.pe

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/BWalti/nf-ssl  This is the exact same code Iam trying to use. My ESP32 is trying download the file from azure blob 
https://firmwarefilestest.blob.core.windows.net/ota/nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32.pe
File size is also very small @DasariKamali

Comment: Just tried to reach the above URL and it gives me a timeout error.